# add a rule into DOCKER-USER from shorewall

Tags: docker, shorewall

I See that the rules that I am adding in `/etc/shorewall/rules` are setup fine but `DOCKER` filter rules are being applied before the ones that I set up in shorewall rules.

I have seen that `DOCKER-USER` can be used to setup docker related rules in iptables. Is there a way to get shorewall to add rules in `DOCKER-USER` table?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be natively supported in Shorewall, and it doesn't appear the creator has any appetite for doing so:

> I have said a number of times that if I were to run Shorewall and Docker
> on one physical system, I would run at least one of them in a virtual
> machine. Note that doing so requires that the Shorewall-generated
> ruleset make the decision about what traffic to send to Docker, but it
> keeps the two products out of each other's hair and insures an
> understandable security framework.

> Also, if I had it to do over again, I would not implement any Docker
> support in Shorewall. I think doing so was a mistake.

- [Tom Eastep, 4 August 2020](https://sourceforge.net/p/shorewall/mailman/shorewall-users/thread/83dcb860-1801-32d6-4c41-b09d89bc2522%40shorewall.net/#msg37077837)

However, if you are willing to dive in to some raw iptables, then you can put the commands in the Shorewall start/stop files.  In the following example, `enp8s0` is my Ethernet interface. It: (0) creates the chain if Docker didn't, perhaps on reboot, (1) allows established traffic to flow out of the containers, (3) allows in ports 80 and 443 arriving on my Ethernet interface, (4) logs the following drop, (5) drops all other traffic arriving to DOCKER-USER from my Ethernet connection.

`/etc/shorewall/start`:

```
iptables -L DOCKER-USER >/dev/null || iptables -N DOCKER-USER
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -i enp8s0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i enp8s0 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 3 -i enp8s0 --match multiport -p tcp --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 4 -i enp8s0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "DOCKER-USER_DROP "
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 5 -i enp8s0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```

`/etc/shorewall/stop`: This makes sure that multiple `shorewall restart`s don't duplicate rules, and that the default RETURN rule that Docker puts in still exists.

```
iptables -F DOCKER-USER
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Then simply `shorewall check && shorewall restart`.  You can also confirm before and after with `iptables -nL DOCKER-USER -v`.

Comment: Umm, why do you have no step "(2)" in your middle paragraph?